# How to take out the texture from each of the faces of a cube in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, perlin-noise

I have been doing some work on P5.js using perlin noise. I have already done a cube with perlin noise texture all over it. But my question is: Can I separate each face's texture?

You may be wondering why would I need this. I need to make a cubemap with it, so I need to take each face's texture and build the image.

I think I will make this crystal clear with images.

This is my cube.

[image]

I need to make something like this
[image]

Now I will show you my code

```
function setup() {

    createCanvas(500,500, WEBGL);
    angleMode(DEGREES)
    noiseDetail(1)
    
    //noLoop();
}

function draw() {

    background(30);
    noStroke();

    translate(0,0, -width)

    rotateX(frameCount * 3)
    rotateY(frameCount * 3)
    

    translate(-width/2, -height/2, -width/2);

    let space = width / 20;
    let indexX = 0;

    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += space) {

        let indexY = 0;
        for(let y = 0; y < height; y += space) {

            let indexZ = 0
            for (let z = 0; z < width; z += space) {
                
                push();

                let h = noise(indexX, indexY, indexZ) * 255;

                fill(h);

                translate(x,y,z)

                box(space);

                pop();

                indexZ += 0.1;
            }

        indexY += 0.1;
        
     }
     indexX += 0.1; 
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you calculate `h`, you should save that along with its `indexX`, `indexY`, `indexZ` (or `x`,`y`,`z`? I'm not entirely sure which variable denotes the position of each pixel in your code) in an array. You could end up with something like:

```js
const myArray =
[
  {
    h: 123123,
    indexX: 234,
    indexY: 345,
    indexZ: 456,
  },
  ...
]
```

Now you have information on what `h` you want to place on each location and you only need to find out how to map each point on the cube surface to a 2 dimensional map like the one you linked.